# Why my json result contains two sections with the same name?

Tags: python, json, simplejson

I use the following code to get json from the string value, update it and return back as string (`simplejson` is used):

```
if text:
    qj = json.loads(text)
else:
    qj = json.loads('{}')
if not qj.get(counter):
    qj[counter] = {}
if not qj.get(counter).get('values'):
    qj[counter]['values'] = []
if not value in qj[counter]['values']: # avoid duplicates
    qj[counter]['values'].append(value)
text = json.dumps(qj)
```

Why do I get the following result if I run the function with the same `counter` value several times (`4` in the example below):

```
{"4": {"values": ["test1"]}, "4": {"values": ["test2"]}}
```

The number of created `4` sections is always 2. If I run the function 3rd time, then first value is updated (not added as I expect).

The expect output should be:

```
{"4": {"values": ["test1", "test2", "test3"]}}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Could you extend your reproducer to be fully standalone (following the guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- thus, removing everything not used in actually reproducing the immediate problem, and ensuring that it actually produces the faulty value in question when directly copy/pasted/run)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I am not sure what you mean. My code doesn't contain anything which is not used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is *not*, however, in direct copy/paste/repro form, as described in the MCVE page or at http://sscce.org/. Which is to say that I couldn't reproduce your bug without writing additional code, however trivial that code might be.

Comment: Well, all you had to do is to run this code twice as hinted in the question: "if I run the function with the same counter value several times [...]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If in your first pass you have following json:

```
{4: {"values": ["test1"]}}
```

You will have this string after `text = json.dumps(qj)`:

```
'{"4": {"values": ["test1"]}}'
```

Now, when loading the json with `qj = json.loads(text)`, you receive:

```
{'4': {'values': ['test1']}} # 4 has turned to '4'!
```

Your check if `4` already exists, fails because it is a number.

So to solve your problem, you can simply turn the counter into a string during the test:

```
if not qj.get(str(counter)):
    ...
```

The reason for this behaviour is that json does not allow integers as keys, see the definition of a *pair* in the [JSON documentation](http://json.org/):

> pair
>
> string : value